# Using system environment variables with Groovy in Jenkin's build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ansible, jenkins-plugins

The Jenkins job uses the **Groovy Postbuild Plugin** to add badges to the build-history. This job also uses an Ansible Playbook that sets an environment variable.

What I'm trying to accomplish, is to use the environment variable in the Groovy post build script.

Ansible:

```
- hosts: all
  connection: local

  vars:
     myenvvar: myvalue

  environment:
     MyEnvVar: "{{ myenvvar }}"
```

Groovy Post Build Script (Jenkins)

```
manager.addShortText("${getEnvVariable(MyEnvVar)}", "black", "white", "0px", "white")
```

My question is, why is Groovy NOT fetching the variable value? Is this because the JVM has it's own environment separate from the actual system?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @techraf good point. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Are you calling Groovy script from within this play?

Comment: @techraf If you mean the Ansible play, then no. The script is being called with the plugin in the Jenkins configuration as a **post build** action.

Comment: So how do you expect a non-related process to have access to the environment of another process?

Comment: @techraf That's what I was thinking and stated in my original question. Hence the challenge is how to **pass** this value.